# Async Download file updating the gui

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I am downloading a file using webclient handling DownloadProgressChanged and DownloadFileCompleted.
My code is working whenever I am not updating the gui with percentage,b but In case I am going to update just a single label with it, then it kind of freezing in random situations. Doesn't matter if the file is little or big.

```
Public WithEvents mclient As New WebClient
    Private Sub Download()

        Dim filepath As String = (filepath..)
        mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        mclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")
        mclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(link), filepath)

    End Sub

    Private Sub mClient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadProgressChanged

        Try
       'file website missing Content-Length, so getting the real size parsing html (real size=label7)
            label1.text= ((e.BytesReceived) / 1048576).ToString("0.00") & "/" & Label7.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub mClient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadFileCompleted
        Try
           label2.text="Download ended"
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

How can I keep label1.text updated without using it inside of DownloadProgressChanged?
If I use a variable on it, where can I keep it updated? I don't want to use a timer though..

Comment: This procedure doesn't *freeze* the Form, it's something else you're doing that does. Something similar to what is described in that comment. Btw, why set `mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` when you're downloading a File?

Comment: This is an empty project and there is nothing else than just that code... 
I suddenly thought about not updating the GUI. For a weird reason endeed, If I just don't write anything under DownloadprogressChanged handler, it doesn't reproduce the freezing.
Also note, I am not saying that the form is freezing constantly, but sometimes it is freezing and updating the label after the download is ended. .
You are right, I don't need that..:D

Comment: There's something else you're doing that you're not showing here.

Comment: For how weird it can look, the only things I am not writing here is obviously the filepath:
My.Settings.DownloadFolder + "\" + title + ".mp3"

Comment: To what cases are you referring to? That code is just setting the text of a Label, it has no impact on the UI. If you see *jumps* in the Label's update, this can be caused by the data transfer itself: it's not a constant flow, there's also some buffering going on. Can't you set just `label1.text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"`

Comment: I dont see just jumps in the label, during those jumps the form is also freezing. I cant drag it too. Cant use that as the website is missing content_lenght. So i am parsing from html the real size of it.

Comment: The code you're showing here is not causing it.

Comment: There is no point to ask a question and hide something. . How does it explain that if I remove everything from the DownloadProgressChanged  than the download is working properly? I am testing lots of url in it.

Comment: Do not write empty catch blocks. They only swallow errors. Get rid of all your Try...End Try blocks for now and see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: Errors like, say, not being allowed to update the UI from a non-GUI thread.  (If that's what's happening, you need to invoke onto the UI thread to update the UI.)

Comment: I am not getting any error since the beginning, is matter of form freezing instead. What you mean with empty try catch blocks? They are not empty.

Comment: Since I m using the same thread, there is no problem of cross threading.

Comment: That's not necessarily a given even for an event handler, but a little research suggests that you are correct and the handler should run on the same thread that called `DownloadFileAsync`.

Comment: I just tested your code, just to be thorough, downloading a video file (~700MB), while playing some animations (24fps) in a very complex Form. There's no freezing. Mary's suggestion to remove the Try/Catch blocks should be followed. Try this:  `BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()))`, see whether it gets better for you. @Craig Those events are raised in the UI Thread.

Comment: The Catch has no code. If you refuse to remove the Try blocks then `Try` `....`  `Catch ex As Exception`  
            `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`  
        `End Try`

Comment: Is it possible, just considering some of the other questions you've asked recently that you maybe have some sort of environmental issue causing "freezing"  Along with you issues opening explorer and this, two processes that shouldn't cause dramatic freezing

Comment: Thanks everybody for spending time helping me. @Hursey, you are right, I had some kind of weird problems lately, which anyway I solved using better methods given from community. In this case, I am trying this in a clean new project, so It shouldn't give problems of any kind about other code issues. 
Jimi here is a gif that show the behavior.. [link](https://imgur.com/a/7dmzHXW)

Comment: Where is that *clock* coming from? Are you updating it every, what, millisecond? Remove that thing.

Comment: I added a clock with DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss.fff") and 100ms interval to give the idea in the gif about the freezing of the form..